# Javascript not working in safari (online)

Tags: javascript, safari

It works fine offline and online on my IOS device, but not on desktop. It pushes a small image file down once user scrolls over 100% window height:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function update() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(window).height()) {
            $('.logo-small').animate({
                "top": '0px'
            }, 300);
        } else {
            $('.logo-small').animate({
                "top": '-90px'
            }, 300);
        }
    }

    setInterval(update, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition should be like below to work in all devices. Without calculating entire document height you will not sure whether the user reached bottom or not. If you need to show your image when user reach 100px from bottom, set value in variable bottomLimit.

```
var bottomLimit = 0;
if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - bottomLimit)
```

Complete Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function update() {
var bottomLimit = 0;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - bottomLimit) {
        $('.logo-small').animate({
            "top": '0px'
        }, 300);
    } else {
        $('.logo-small').animate({
            "top": '-90px'
        }, 300);
    }
}

setInterval(update, 1000);
</script>
```